# Sum column values while looping over a query result set

Tags: php, loops, pdo, sum

The following script shows the product and the quantity.
Par example: *t-shirt(1), boxershort(2*).

Now I would like to show the sum of all items, in this case "3".

How can I get an array_sum of this?

```
$allItems = "";
$items = array();
$select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(product, ' (', quantity,')') AS ItemQty, price 
FROM database");
$select_stmt->execute();
while ($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $items[] = $row["ItemQty"];
}
$allItems = implode(", ", $items);
```

Comment: Don't do the concatenation in the query. Select the data you need so you can do direct calculations on it and only concatenate when you actually need to display it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should do this:

```
<?php
$allItems = "";
$items = array();
$select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(product, ' (', quantity,')') AS ItemQty, price 
FROM database");
$select_stmt->execute();
while ($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $row["ItemQty"], $match);
    array_push($items, (int)$match);
}
echo array_sum($items);
$allItems = implode(", ", $items);
?>
```

Comment: When writing an answer, you should include an explanation of why they should to it like this, like what you've changed and why.

Comment: Won't work. `ItemQty` is a string such as `t-shirt(1)`, not an integer.

Comment: @El_Vanja i edit my answer, with regex i export number and push it to array and then sum all numbers

Answer (score 1):

Avoid selecting data in a way that fits the purpose of displaying it. What you should do instead is grab only the data:

```
$select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT product, quantity, price FROM database");
```

Then you can easily do calculations with raw numbers:

```
while ($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $items[] = $row["quantity"];
}
$sum = array_sum($items);
```

and have the display value created in PHP:

```
$displayItem = sprintf('%s (%d)', $row['product'], $row['quantity']);
```

If you insist, you could get that display string directly from the query, but then do it as an additional field:

```
$select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT product, quantity, price, CONCAT(product, ' (', quantity,')') AS ItemQty FROM database");
```

This way you still have `quantity` as a number to do calculations with and `ItemQty` to use for displaying purposes.